# ASP.Net MVC - which is the best approach for multi select grouping using JQuery Dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

This is my scenario

I have an view(page) with list of items, a user could select single or multiple items from this page and click on a "Add to Group" button. Then a modal dialog(JQuery dialog) will be shown, from that he could select group, then press the add button. Which causes the items selected in the parent page is added to that particular group.

So, which is the best way to pass the selected items to the modal pop-up?

1. Though the query string ? - what happens if the no:of items selected is large, will the url support that much characters
2. Keep the list in the parent page in a javascript variable and return the selected group from the modal pop-up?

Or is there is any other better option?

Thanks,

[Rajeesh](http://wwww.rajeeshcv.com)

Answer (score 0):

2a. There is no "parent" page; modal dialog is part of the same page as selected items. Therefore on "OK" function from the dialog you can go through the checked items and do whatever you want, including POSTing to the server. It's not clear from your post whether "adding items to the group" happens on the server or client

Comment: Adding to the group happens in server side